# pl/sql: how can I write this query?

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

I have two columns (both primary) [PLAYER_ID] [LEAUGE_ID]

something like this:

```
Player_id      League_id
2139            8
2153            8
2302            10
2441            8
2441            10
```

I am trying to find the same player who played in both leagues

According to the table above, I am trying to only find:

```
Player_id     League_id_1     League_id_2
2441          8               10
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the alteration on your question, your final result doesn't even match your sample data. You would not get any result based on your sample.  For future reference, you should post another question instead of altering your question after it has been answered & accepted.

Comment: I just realized the answer wasn't right primarily because i didn't ask it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having it in rows:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Player_id
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY Player_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(League_id)) FROM myTable)
) p ON t.Player_id = p.Player_id
```

This should return:

```
Player_id    League_id
2441         8
2441         10
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/961c2/11)

Answer (score 9):

It appears that you want this in row one.  So you can use the following to get it in one row using a `PIVOT`:

```
select player_id,
  league_id_1,
  league_id_2
from
(
  select t1.player_id, t1.league_id,
    row_number() over(partition by t1.player_id order by t1.league_id) rn
  from table1 t1
  inner join
  (
    select player_id
    from table1
    group by player_id
    having count(distinct league_id) > 1
  ) t2
    on t1.player_id = t2.player_id
) x
pivot
(
  max(league_id)
  for rn in (1 as league_id_1, 2 as league_id_2)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8395c/10)

or if you don't have access to the `PIVOT` function, you can use a `CASE` statement with aggregate:

```
select player_id,
  max(case when rn = 1 then league_id end) league_id_1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then league_id end) league_id_2
from
(
  select t1.player_id, t1.league_id,
    row_number() over(partition by t1.player_id order by t1.league_id) rn
  from table1 t1
  inner join
  (
    select player_id
    from table1
    group by player_id
    having count(distinct league_id) > 1
  ) t2
    on t1.player_id = t2.player_id
) x
group by player_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0145d/1)

If you don't want it in one row, then you can just use the inner sub-query:

```
  select t1.player_id, t1.league_id
  from table1 t1
  inner join
  (
    select player_id
    from table1
    group by player_id
    having count(distinct league_id) > 1
  ) t2
    on t1.player_id = t2.player_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0145d/4)

Comment: @user1683987 your question before the edit was already answered by this one. if you have alterations on it, don't unaccept the answer but instead create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use PIVOT(11g only), and you want output all   League_id in one row, try this:

```
            DECLARE
               v_owner VARCHAR2 ( 40 );
               v_player_id VARCHAR2 ( 40 );
               v_league_id VARCHAR2 ( 100 );
               v_league_id_total VARCHAR2 ( 1000 );

               /* First cursor */
               CURSOR get_player_id
               IS
                  SELECT DISTINCT player_id
                  FROM            table1
                  ORDER BY        player_id;

               /* Second cursor */
               CURSOR get_league_id
               IS
                  SELECT   league_id
                  FROM     table1
                  WHERE    player_id = v_player_id
                  ORDER BY league_id;
            BEGIN
               -- Open first cursor
               OPEN get_player_id;

               LOOP
                  FETCH get_player_id
                  INTO  v_player_id;

                  v_league_id_total := '';
                  EXIT WHEN get_player_id%NOTFOUND;

                  -- Open 2nd cursor
                  OPEN get_league_id;

                  LOOP
                     FETCH get_league_id
                     INTO  v_league_id;

                     EXIT WHEN get_league_id%NOTFOUND;
                     v_league_id_total := v_league_id_total || ' , ' || v_league_id;
                  END LOOP;

                  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( RPAD ( v_player_id,
                                                26,
                                                ' '
                                              ) ||
                                         RPAD ( v_league_id_total,
                                                26,
                                                ' '
                                              ) );

                  CLOSE get_league_id;
               END LOOP;

               CLOSE get_player_id;
            EXCEPTION
               WHEN OTHERS
               THEN
                  raise_application_error ( -20001,
                                            'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                            SQLCODE ||
                                            ' -ERROR- ' ||
                                            SQLERRM );
            END;
```

Output will like this:

```
2139     , 8                      
2153     , 8                      
2303     , 8 , 10   (I added one more record.)              
2441     , 8 , 10 , 11 , 12   (I added 2 more records)
```